# When using Rack:Auth:Basic, how do I sign out?

Tags: authentication

One link I saw said that if you login with HTTP Basic Authentication (Rack:Auth:Basic) then you can't really log out without killing cookies in your browser. So there's no good way to log out.

Another link said to use Rack::Session::Pool and then do a session.clear to logout.

What's the correct approach?